# SQL Replace Value based one digit

Tags: sql

I have a column below need to be replaced by some text based on their third digit of the data.
For example, Y = Yellow, B = Blue etc.
I'm thinking if case and Mid function can be used ?
Thanks for your help in advance !

```
K-Y004
K-B390
K-G200
K-Y980
K-B200

UPDATE [Table]
SET [Table],[Column] = CASE
WHEN MID( [Table],[Column], 3,1) = "B", THEN "Blue"
WHEN MID( [Table],[Column], 3,1) = "G", THEN "Green"
```

Comment: Or just use substring for simplicity over the mid thing? And lose the comma in the case and provide an end.

Comment: Add your sample data with expected result.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS in use here - answers can vary materially between each.

Comment: `MID()` is not a standard SQL function, so in general you cannot use it although there might be a database that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Like firmament mentioned in the comments above, losing the extra comma, maybe using single quotes in place of double quotes, and having an END of the case should work.

This works for me:-

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET [COLUMN]= (CASE
WHEN MID([COLUMN], 3,1)='B' THEN 'Blue'
WHEN MID([COLUMN], 3,1)='G' THEN 'Green'
WHEN MID([COLUMN], 3,1)='Y' THEN 'Yellow' end);
```

Suggestion:-

Possibly this can be simplified into

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET [COLUMN]= (CASE MID([COLUMN], 3,1)
WHEN 'B' THEN 'Blue'
WHEN 'G' THEN 'Green'
WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Yellow' end);
```

Had this been an Oracle-based question, we could have done better with DECODE.

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET [COLUMN]= (DECODE(MID([COLUMN], 3,1), 'B', 'Blue', 'G', 'Green', 'Y', 'Yellow', 'Default');
```

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh Thakur !
I'm using Access on these code, I tried to apply your suggestion, but not sure why Syntax error pop up. 
Syntax error (missing operator) in query express (Case ..........) 
Do you have any advise on this ?
Thanks